# Symfony2 & Doctrine - Get number of rows returned from datasource

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code in my Symfony2 Repository Class...

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('foo')
        ->where('foo.bar = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $myID)
        ->getQuery();
```

How do I get the number of rows found by the database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to execute DQL to do something you want.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
              ->from('foo', 'f')
              ->where('foo.bar = :id')
              ->setParameter('id', $myID)
              ->getQuery();


$total = $query->select('COUNT(f)')
               ->getQuery()
               ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: This is poor solution + it doesn't work in newer Symfony2 - use the answer below instead.

Answer (score 34):

I think you can do something like that:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('COUNT(f.id)') 
    ->from('foo', 'f')
    ->where('foo.bar = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $myID)
    ->getQuery();

$total = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: This is a great answer because I think it only requires one database query.

Answer (score 22):

You execute the query then get the results. When you have the results, you get the number of record by doing a `count` on the results:

```
$results = $query->getResult();
$resultCount = count($results);
```

If you are concerned with paging, like getting 25 records out of the total. Then, you have two choices.

- You perform the query twice, one time to get total results, another time to retrieve only 25 results using the method `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`. This method `setFirstResult` enable you to set the offset and the second, `setMaxResults`, number of records. The following code will give you results ranging from 25 to 50, it's the second page if you use 25 records by page.

  `$query->setFirstResult(25);`
  `$query->setMaxResults(25);`
- You can check doctrine-extensions for Doctrine2 which have paginator support. These extensions have been made by one of the developer of Doctrine2. You can review these [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

Hope this help.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: @Reuven answer is a bit better, for the count part, because it uses the internal `COUNT` function of the database manager. It is better because the results are not transferred to get the count. My other comments still apply.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my answer is better only if you need only the count, and not the objects.

Comment: I'd rather your answer, cause it apply for any query. When you have complex queries (with another count() for example) it could easily  be applied! Thx

Comment: @Matt : can you give example on how to do the count if you have pagination? thanks

Comment: @aizele Everything is write-up in this question. Issue a `COUNT` query without pagination to retrieve number of **total** records. Then do a paginated query (same as `COUNT` query, but with actual fields you want) and paginate using `setFirstResults` (offset) and `setMaxResults` (count per page). You can even share great parts of both query by looking at @Reuven answer's above.

Comment: @Matt : thanks,, I got it already,,, but how can I put something like this : `Showing 1 to 10 of 12 results ` and paginate it also like when I click page 1 it will give that result,, and then if I click page 2 it will display `showing 11 to 12 of 12 results`?

Comment: Well, your `COUNT` query gives your total records, you know how many records in the paginated query (`count($results)`). You have all information to show `Showing 1 to 10 of 12`, it's simple mathematics. You're on your own for this part.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer, that still works when there is a group statement involved. Thanks!

Comment: It seems only answer. I have used it many times but sometimes when working with millions of records executing two queries consume much memory and load time. I am just looking for alternate way to optimize it when working on bigdata

Answer (score 8):

I think this is as concise as it gets:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('entity');
$qb->select('COUNT(entity)');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Where `$repo` is of type `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`