# Symfony2 and Doctrine2: High memory usage when querying for object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two (for this question relevant) Entities which are in a many (certificates) to one (policy) relationship:

- Certificate
- Policy

...which basically look like this:

```
class Policy {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Akm\CertificateBundle\Entity\Certificate", mappedBy="policies")
     */
    private $certificates;

    /**
     * Get template (assuming there is only one
     * per policy (which should be the case) and return the Certificate
     * object. If (for some reason) there is more than only one template,
     * then only the first one will be returned.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTemplate() {
        $certificates = $this->getCertificates();
        foreach($certificates as $cert) {
           if ($cert->getIsTemplate()) {
              return $cert;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Certificate {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isTemplate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Akm\CertificateBundle\Entity\Policy", inversedBy="certificates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="policy_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $policies;
}
```

(and of course the corresponding getters and setter, auto-generated by doctrine) The problem with this approach is, that if I call a controller, which itself calls the `removeTemplate()`-function, I get a `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate [...] bytes) in [...]`; I think, that the problem is the foreach-loop, which fetches the certificate object and tests its property `isTemplate`. Because the certificate-objects are quite large, this results in too high memory usage (resulting in a error message) if there are about 80 certificates or more.

Now I wonder, how I could solve this problem. I had two ideas / approaches, which didn't work as expected.

The first one was to `unset()` the `$cert`-variable as soon as I know, that I don't need it anymore:

```
public function getTemplate() {
    $certificates = $this->getCertificates();
    foreach($certificates as $cert) {
       if ($cert->getIsTemplate()) {
          return $cert;
       } else {
          unset($cert);
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, this didn't change anything, the controller still used the same amount of memory.

So I thought about just replacing all calls of the `getTemplate()`-function inside the controllers with the following (where the `$pol`-variable is an object of the Policy-entity):

```
$template = $cert_repository->findBy(
                    array('isTemplate' => true),
                    array('policies' => $pol->getId());
```

(I used the `$pol->getId()` instead of just the Policy-object because of this [StackOverflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625042/1202500))

The problem with this approach is, that I always get a `Unrecognized field: policies`-error and I don't know why.

I hope that someone can help me to get one of these approaches working (I would prefer the first one, because I don't have to change anything in the controllers then).

Thanks in advance,
katze_sonne

Comment: What is the goal of `getTemplate()`? The `return $cert;` will return only one certificate. Maybe you should add a function to your repository in order to get only the first valid certificate associated to the certificate.

Comment: @n.1:
Well, I'm sorry, I forgot to describe this function more detailed in my question.

For each policy, there is (only) one related template (therefore only one certificate is returned) (but many related certificates). There can be templates which aren't related to policies though. A template in this case is just a certificate with `isTemplate == true`.

So the goal of `getTemplate()` is to find _that_ single certificate which has `isTemplate` set to `true` _and_ which is related to _this_ policy.

What exactly do you mean by "add a function to your repository"? To the certificate-entity?

Comment: What kind of objects the `getCertificates()` function in the `Certificate` repository return? I don't see the link from a `Certificate` to a `Policy` in your code.

Comment: Ohhhh... now I see your point. It was a really stupid copy-paste-mistake, I included when copying the code-snippets into stackoverflow -.- I'm sorry. The `getTemplates()`-function belonged into the `Policy`-repository. I hope that now someone can answer my question :/ thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- You could paginate your results
- You could hydrate your results into arrays

You could do something like this

```
$query = $this->cert_repository
              ->createQueryBuilder('p')
              ->select(array('p'))
              ->where('p.isTemplate = :isTemplate')->setParameter('isTemplate', true)
              ->andWhere('p.policies = :policies')->setParameter('policies', $pol->getId())
              ->getQuery()
              ->setFirstResult($offset)
              ->setMaxResults($limit);
return $query->getArrayResult();
```

Basically, when Doctrine hydrates objects, it keeps reference of the object's data into memory and using the function `unset` will not free the memory, however hydrating the objects into arrays lets you use the function `unset`.

Comment: First let me thank you for your answer! I had a look at the [Query Builder Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). Most instructions are clear to me now. But I don't understand what exactly is returned - and array of certificate objects? I think your example shows how to "paginate" the results, correct? If so, how can I get the total number of rows? Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8226874/1202500) the only way? Do I still need to do a `unset()` then?

Comment: I've now tried to integrate this into my Controller. The goal was to get the template-ID of the related template. [This](http://pastebin.com/VKSzT7zD) is my code so far. I'm still a little bit confused about what some of the instructions are doing and if my approach is correct at all. Of course I still get the memory exhaustion error. Actually the longer I look at the code, the more confused I get :/ I hope you can help me with that!

Comment: Let's walk through your problem on pastbin, just add comment on your code so we can talk this through

Comment: I tried to comment the code as good as I can: http://pastebin.com/mTRe1RPQ I hope it's somewhat understandable ;)