# Doctrine return array of array for a scalar query

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

With doctrine and the query builder I write a `SELECT MAX()` query, and when this result is passed to another query builder, as a parameter, the query works just fine.

But for some reason, I use native SQL query elsewhere in another Repository, and when I use `$repo->getMaxMyThing()`, it return me an array of array like 
`array(array('1' => 42))`.

Not that if I want the result, I need to type: `$max[0]['1']` (The 0 is a simple array index, but the '1' is a string associated key).

Did any method exists in the Doctrine Bundle to 'convert' it to a simple integer automatically?

Comment: show code of method getMaxMyThing

Comment: Have you tried to use [getSingleScalarResult()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8227101/2257664)?

Comment: @A.L It works, thank you and sorry I completely forget to give you a response. Answer the question so I can validate.

Comment: @rickozoe Thanks for the ping! I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't want Doctrine to return entities, you can use the [get*ScalarResult() query methods](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats).

> - `Query#getScalarResult()`: Retrieves a flat/rectangular result set of scalar values that can contain duplicate data. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.
> - `Query#getSingleScalarResult()`: Retrieves a single scalar value from the result returned by the dbms. If the result contains more than a single scalar value, an exception is thrown. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM Entities\User u');
$count = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

`$count` will be a single value (not an array) as requested.